# simple xml problem/google checkout... bozo

Tags: php, kohana, google-checkout

Hey guys im feeding a curl response into a simple xml object.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($redirect);
```

$xml.asXml() gets me this ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkout-redirect xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="9160aabc-  5efe-4f9e-bb90-71ce75d7815f">
<redirect-url>https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/view/buy?  o=shoppingcart&amp;shoppingcart=222826053769344</redirect-url>
</checkout-redirect>
```

when I do: $xml->redirect-url

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Use of undefined constant url - assumed 'url'
die(var_dump($xml->redirect-url));
```

shouldn't I be able to access it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `$xml->{'redirect-url'}` ?

I really don't know if that works, but you can give it a try :D

Comment: "redirect-url" is an incorrect variable name (due to the "-").

Comment: how do i get around that Leki? this is a response from google, so I have no ability to change it without crazy hacks.. and i dont wanna go down that road.

Comment: `$xml->{'redirect-url'}` didn't work (instead of `$xml->redirect-url`) ?

Comment: this returns: object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) { [0]=> string(88) "https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/view/buy?o=shoppingcart&shoppingcart=819902860469198" }

Comment: hooray thanks! LekisS    $this->request->redirect($xml->{'redirect-url'});
works perfect!